# How to add a circular image in Material-UI Card?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to create a User Card and I want the image of the User to be circular. By default the image is rectangular. Adding "border-radius: 50%" doesn't work either.

Comment: [Circular Paper](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/paper) ,[Card](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/card)

Comment: It helps if you include the code you currently have

Comment: You got to add height and width along with the border-radius in order to make it circular

Comment: what have you done so far? Its always good to share code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this CSS in your CardMedia class.

```
cardMedia: {
    paddingTop: '81.25%',
    borderRadius: '50%',
    margin: '28px'
},
```